Is there a way to prevent lost focus event from triggering before/after update event in Microsoft Access?
Does calling a procedure from the AfterUpdate event in a combobox control cause the control to lose focus and trigger the record's Before/After Update event? I have an undo method in the BeforeUpdate event. If the user undoes the record, a procedure has already been called, which contains a record save method, and of course an error occurs because a record cannot be saved if there aren't any changes.
I need a little help with my logic. Should I just do an error handler, or should I reconsider where I am calling my procedures from.
Apparently, I need code...
Sub SomeProcedure()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    'Do some stuff in here...
End Sub

Private ComboBox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.BooleanSomeControl.Value = False
    Call SomeProcedure ' This apparently causes the control to lose focus
End Sub 

Private Form_BeforeUpdate()
    If x=x Then
      Me.Undo
      Cancel = True
End Sub

Programmatically, I think the combobox AfterUpdate event is triggering the form's BeforeUpdate...wait.
I think I need to realize why I am using a particular procedure in a particular event.
The other thing I need to figure out is where I should be assigning values to controls (in the event or in a called procedure).
Perhaps setting a condition that checks the record before attempting save.

I tested your code. Combobox does not lose focus when I simply select item from list which triggers AfterUpdate event.

If you type in box and then Tab or Enter, combobox will lose focus, same as a textbox would.

If the combobox loses the focus depends on the way the user select an entry. If the user uses the mouse to select an entry, the AfterUpdate event will be fired but the focus stays. If the user uses the keyboard and uses Tab or Enter, the focus will move to another control. This you can't avoid, otherwise the user could never leave the control. Maybe  saving the combobox name in a variable when something changed can be helping so that you know what happened before and you can react accordingly. For more help show for what reason you need to have the focus still on the combobox.

The core of the steps are all there in the procedure. A checkbox value is set to false, a procedure is called, and that procedure contains a command to save the record. If the record has not changed, then the save command generates an error. I have not tried a conditional statement to escape the unchanged record. Additionally, which is not include in my example is a Form_BeforeUpdate event containing some validation procedures and the option to undo changes to the record. This is where the undesired behavior is occurring: generally, undo and cancel = true should cancel the update, right?

I think I got it. Okay, the combobox's AfterUpdate is calling SomeProcedure and attempting to save a record that has not changed (undo command put the record in an unchanged state). So, I guess I don't need to 'Cancel' any events. I need a condition to escape the save command when the record has not changed.

Try If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False instead of DoCmd.
